# unable to save mysql queries generated from EntityFramework to Nlog through miniprofiler

Tags: mysql, logging, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5, miniprofiler

I was looking for an open source alternate to [EntityProfiler](https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf).  My project is in EF 5.0.0 and I tried MiniProfiler.  Since It is a webapi project, I could not see the trace information in the UI.  Managed to find [vxcore.nlog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VXCore.NLog.MiniProfiler/) nuget 
but it could not log the sql queries generated from Entity Framework.
This is my code

```
 private static Logger mlogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
 mlogger.Trace("mylog information");
 NLogStorage.SetAsStorage(mlogger, LogLevel.Debug); 

using (var test = new testEntities()) {
                var updatedUser = test.students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.StudentName == "John");
            }
mlogger.Trace("mylog information end");
```

This is my logfile output

**20170324013230 SCI-LT-050 at 23-03-2017 20:02:30  http://localhost:61308/ = 4,986.4ms (sql = 23.7ms in 6 cmds)**

The log above shows only the sql executed time but not the queries.  Could anybody help?

Comment: Can't you upgrade to EF6?

Comment: I accept your question valid. The codebase is large and the plan in progress and takes time.  Isn't there a way to do in ef5 for now?

Comment: Before EF6, I used [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers) for logging.

Comment: my upvotes. Seems to be valid. I will try that and post here shortly.

Comment: i found eflogger helpful. https://eflogger.codeplex.com/